# Slidepuzzle, switch Icons

Tags: java, arrays, image, icons

We are making a slidepuzzle in java using Eclipse. We have put `Icon`s on buttons. Now we want to switch the `Icon` of the button we click on with the icon of the so called 'Empty button'.

```
int location =(new Integer(e.getActionCommand())).intValue(); //The buttons are in an Array:  "Pieces[]", Location: index
if (Bounds(location,InvisibleButton)) {
//The method Bounds, is one we made to see if the two pieces are next to eachother,
Icon temp;  //Temporar ButtonIcon
temp=Knop[location].getIcon(); 
Pieces[location].setIcon(Piece[InvisibleButton].getIcon()); 
Pieces[InvisibleButton].setIcon(temp); 
InvisibleButton = location; 
}
```

Why don't the Icons switch places?

Errors:

It only gives an error when we click on a piece next to the empty piece, we can click all others. The code works but it breaks the moment we want to switch the images.
here is the error code:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Mozaiq.Schuifpuzzelpaneel.actionPerformed(Schuifpuzzelpaneel.java:93)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
at     javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6382)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3275)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6147)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2083)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4744)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2141)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4572)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4619)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4280)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4210)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2127)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2489)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4572)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:710)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:669)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:667)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:683)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:681)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:680)
at     java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at     java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick guess : call the repaint() method.

Probably somthing like:

```
Pieces[location].repaint();
```

at the end of you function.

Comment: Also try calling `revalidate()` on your Piece.

Comment: I tried that,  but didn't work. Eclipse seems not able to get the Icon. We always get the same error;

Comment: I'm a little confused; this is an Android app, right? Eclipse should have nothing to with whether or not your app can access the icons. Please show us the error message.

Comment: I edited my question. The error code is there. I couldn't post it here. Not enough space. I'm new to this site. Thank you for answering :)

Comment: OK - So it is at NULL-pointer. What is in the line: Schuifpuzzelpaneel.java:93

Comment: temp=Knop[location].getIcon();

Comment: `Knop[location]` has not instantiated. Can you share the code where you instantiate the `Knop` array?

Comment: Yes of course. But what do you mean by instantiate? We're not english, I'm sorry

Comment: Do you mean this?
private JButton[] stukjes;                                     
stukjes = new JButton[dimensie*dimensie];                     stukjes[i] = new JButton();

Comment: Yes, `stukjes[i] = new JButton();` is an example of instantiating (i.e. creating an instance of) a JButton object.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem seems to be that `Knop[location]` does not conatin a reference to a piece object. Maybe this is a better way to do it:

```
int location =(new Integer(e.getActionCommand())).intValue(); 
//The buttons are in an  Array:  "Pieces[]", Location: index
if (Bounds(location,InvisibleButton)) {
  //The method Bounds, is one we made to see if the two pieces are next to eachother,
  Icon temp;  //Temporar ButtonIcon

  temp=Pieces[location].getIcon(); //<-------------------Changed this line

  Pieces[location].setIcon(Piece[InvisibleButton].getIcon()); 
  Pieces[InvisibleButton].setIcon(temp); 
  InvisibleButton = location; 
}
```

Errors;

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Mozaiq.Schuifpuzzelpaneel.actionPerformed(Schuifpuzzelpaneel.java:136)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
at    javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6382)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3275)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6147)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2083)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4744)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2141)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4572)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4619)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4280)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4210)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2127)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2489)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4572)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:710)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:669)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:667)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at    java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at  java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:683)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:681)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:680)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at    java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Comment: I'm gonna try that in a second

Comment: I put my errors in your answer. Line 136 is the line you edited;
temp=Pieces[location].getIcon();

Comment: Can you put the code in your question where you create the `Pieces[]` array  and call `setIcon()` on each `Piece`?